# Difference between percussive massage devices?

Tags: muscle-recovery

I recently did a CrossFit competition and there was a company offering free recovery treatments. One of the options was a percussion massage using a massage gun. It helped loosen up my back immediately. Naturally, I started looking into various percussion massage devices and found that there are two styles. One is the “gun” (looks like a jigsaw) and the other is a wand.

I can only find information comparing guns to guns and wands to wands. The wands are significantly less expensive than the guns. I want to know if guns are more effective than wands for recovery?